ROS Noetic Camera Calibration Code Issues
I've been having some trouble with a ROS camera calibration project for a little while now.
I've written and compiled a C++ program in ROS Noetic to recognize a chessboard pattern to calibrate a webcam.
The program has been written such that all of the image gathering and processing occurs within the C++ executable using VideoCapture cap(0) and imshow().
The program should not need a publisher and subscriber node structure for inputting, processing, and outputting frames and matrices from a webcam feed.
The C++ program compiles without any errors. However, when it is rosrun it executes infinitely and does not seem to be able to find the checkerboards and does not display any output windows or any  output any complete matrices (or anything other than a blank command line to let me know it's running for that matter). The only ways to escape the program after it starts running is either by closing the command window or typing the kill command.
Software Versions:
Ubuntu 64-bit version 20.04.4 LTS
OpenCV2 library version 4.2.0
ROS noetic
cmake version 3.16.3
GNU make version 4.2.1
The C++ code:
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
 
 Mat frame,cropped_left_image,cropped_right_image,fullframe; 
 
     vector<Point2f> cornersRight; //this will be filled by the detected corners
     vector<Point2f> cornersLeft; //these vectors store the left and right corner locations
     Point2f offset(0,432); //half 1280X720 frame. This value sets the offset for coordinate correction
     
     const char* window_name4 = "Complete Frame";  
 


bool detectAndDrawLeftChessboardCorners()
{
    Size patternsize(8,6); //interior number of corners
    Mat gray; // Matrix to store the gray scale image 
    cvtColor(cropped_left_image,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);//source image
     //this will be filled by the detected corners

    //CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK saves a lot of time on images that do not contain any chessboard corners
    bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, cornersLeft,
                        CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
                        + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK); //find the chessboard corners and send them to corners left

    if(patternfound)
        cornerSubPix(gray, cornersLeft, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), 
            TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 30, 0.1));

    drawChessboardCorners(cropped_left_image, patternsize, Mat(cornersLeft), patternfound);

    return true;
}

bool detectAndDrawRightChessboardCorners()
{
    Size patternsize(8,6); //interior number of corners
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(cropped_right_image,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);//source image
    //CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK saves a lot of time on images that do not contain any chessboard corners
    bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, cornersRight,
                        CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
                        + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK); //find the chessboard corners and send them to corners right

    if(patternfound)
        cornerSubPix(gray, cornersRight, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), 
            TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 30, 0.1));

    drawChessboardCorners(cropped_right_image, patternsize, Mat(cornersRight), patternfound);

    return true;
}


void compensateRightOffset(){
    for(int i =0; i < cornersRight.size(); i++){ 
        cornersRight[i]+=offset;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 
 VideoCapture cap(0);  //Open the default video camera (USB webcam)

 if (cap.isOpened() == false) //if not success, exit program
 {
  cout << "Cannot open the video camera" << endl;
  cin.get(); //wait for any key press
  return -1;
 } 

 double dWidth = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); 
 double dHeight = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); 

 cout << "Resolution of the video : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;


 while (true)
 {
  bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video 
  if (bSuccess == false) 
  {
   cout << "Video camera is disconnected" << endl;
   cin.get(); //Wait for any key press
   break;
  }
  
  cropped_left_image = frame(Range(0,(int)(dHeight)),Range(0,(0.6*dWidth)));
  detectAndDrawLeftChessboardCorners(); 

  cropped_right_image = frame(Range(0,dHeight),Range((0.4*dWidth),dWidth));
  detectAndDrawRightChessboardCorners(); 

  Mat cropped_left_full_display = cropped_left_image(Range(0,dHeight),Range(0,0.5*dWidth));
  Mat cropped_right_full_display = cropped_right_image(Range(0,dHeight),Range(128,0.5*dWidth));
 
  hconcat(cropped_left_full_display,cropped_right_full_display,fullframe);
  compensateRightOffset(); 
  
  imshow(window_name4, fullframe); 
 
  if (waitKey(10) == 27)
  {
   cout << "Esc key is pressed by user. Stoppig the video" << endl;
   break;
  }
 }

 return 0;

}

I don't understand how this type of error could be occuring in this situation, and I would appreciate any help with this problem. I do not believe this is a lighting issue as I have tested this program in multiple environmeents with different overhead lighting conditions and got the same result every time.
